# Windows 10 adjust extremely fast typing

Tags: windows, windows-10, typing

I'm a linux user, who switched to win10 and want to adjust super-fast typing like an max setting in ubuntu.
At the current time i found that maximum speed i can reach are from following settings :

```
AutoRepeatDelay 0
AutoRepeatRate 0
BounceTime 0
DelayBeforeAcceptance 0
Flags 58 (filter keys disabled)
```

But it's not enough for me =(
Is there any way to gain more speed from keyboard ?

Comment: Do you already have a low-latency keyboard?

Comment: You mean hardware ? My laptop keyboard was unbelievable fast on linux and i want achieve the same on win.

Comment: How fast do you type... exactly?

Comment: Unless you are a pro-gamer the speed of keypress is really not that important

Answer (score 0):

Based on this link:
https://ludditus.com/2016/07/15/microsoft-the-keyboard-repeat-rate-and-sleeping-how-to-work-around-their-idiocy/
I figured out the problem.
Apparently, registry key "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Accessibility\Keyboard Response\flags" = 27 force to interact with windows "Filter Keys" option and all other keys above now works as expected.

Comment: Where do you set this flag and how do you know exactly what this value achieves?

Comment: from this arcticle : https://ludditus.com/2016/07/15/microsoft-the-keyboard-repeat-rate-and-sleeping-how-to-work-around-their-idiocy/

Comment: @SomeJun Please edit the answer to include the relevant information from the link.